# Differentiability in metric spaces

Tags: derivatives, metric-spaces

I have a question in mind:   Why can't we define differentiability in arbitrary metric spaces? Or can we define it really? Please discuss. I only have studied the notion of differentiability in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$, so you need an addition and a division -> only vectorial spaces. And $R^n$ is not that handiy for dividing by a vector that's why you have partial derivatives

Comment: vectorial spaces means?? @ Thomas

Comment: To see how weird such a notion might get (if you could even define it), consider what would a derivative look like on, for example, the space $\{ 0, 1, \dotsc, n \}$ endowed with the discrete metric?

Comment: @Mathematics http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space

Comment: @Thomas The definition of derivative as the limit of divided differences is handy in calculus, but it is not the most fundamental definition. The fundamental notion is a linear approximation to $f$ (sometimes called the *total derivative*), which works equally well in all dimensions, including infinite-dimensional spaces with no preferred coordinate system. The concept of a partial derivatives is of relatively minor importance.

Comment: @Thomas For example, differentiability makes perfect sense - and is widely used - on [smooth manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold), which do not have the structure of a vector space.

Comment: @PostNoBills Thanks for the enlightening, I didn't know that

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Riemannian manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold) are the primary example of  metric spaces which have a useful notion of differentiability, despite not necessarily being  $\mathbb R^n$ or any kind of vector space.  (One does not actually need the Riemannian structure to define derivatives; only the smooth structure is needed. But you asked about *metric* spaces, and general smooth manifolds do not have a preferred metric.)

One can push a bit of calculus into the realm of metric spaces that are not smooth manifolds. This subject (*Analysis on metric spaces*)  gets pretty technical and axiomatic   quickly, but there are strong recent results, with  applications to other areas like   embeddings of infinite graphs into normed spaces. A standard reference is the survey [Nonsmooth calculus](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2007-44-02/S0273-0979-07-01140-8/) by Heinonen:

> We survey recent advances in analysis and geometry, where first order differential analysis has been extended beyond its classical smooth settings. Such studies have applications to geometric rigidity questions, but are also of intrinsic interest. The transition from smooth spaces to singular spaces where calculus is possible parallels the classical development from smooth functions to functions with weak or generalized derivatives. Moreover, there is a new way of looking at the classical geometric theory of Sobolev functions that is useful in more general contexts.

Comment: Notice though that your statement about not being a vector space for arbitrary Riemannian structures is not strictly speaking true because the smooth structure requires an attached vector space structure,namely the tangent space. It really doesn't make sense to talk about derivatives without a vector space structure of some kind since derivatives are linear maps by definition. That's important for beginners to understand.