# Taking the derivative of a set function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Lets say $f(A)$ is a set function $A \to \mathbb{R}$ for a collection of sets $\mathcal{A}$.

Is is possible to differentiate such a function, and if so, what theory is used to give this notion a rigorous foundation? Or maybe, is it only possible if $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma-$field with measure $|\mu(A)|<\infty\;\forall A\in \mathcal{A}$.

**Here are my attempts and thoughts about this**

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the collection of sets upon which $f(A)$ is defined. To make this easier, assume that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-Field.

If I define a decreasing sequence of sets $A_i \in \mathcal{A}: A_1 \supset A_2 \supset A_3 ... \supset A$ so that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} A_i = A$, then I have something like the univariate $x\to \infty$.

However, the problem is that $A \in \mathcal{A}$ need not define a metric space, so I can't just assign an absolute distance to each set in the decreasing sequence, right? If I could, that would essentially just translate this to univariate calculus. I think if I define a measure over the field $\mathcal{A}$ I could also make this easier, but that would be the Radon-Nikodym derivative (unless that *is* the derivative of a set function).

I thought maybe the following could work too. Let's define distance between two sets $A,B$ in the domain of $f(\cdot)$ as:

$$d(A,B) := \left|\sup_{x \in A, \;y \in B\cap A^c } |f(x)-f(y)| - \sup_{x \in B, \;y \in A\cap B^c } |f(x)-f(y)|\right|$$

With this, I thought we could define a derivative from this as:

$$f'(A) := \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(A_{i+1})-f(A_{i})}{d(A_{i+1},A_{i})}$$

Comment: Somewhat related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614688/differentiability-in-metric-spaces

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä (+1) Thanks! Indeed, I may have inadvertently turned $\mathcal{A}$ into a metric space.

Comment: An issue with your distance function is that it is not defined if one of the sets is a subset of the other, making $B \cap A^c$ or $A \cap B^c$ empty.

Comment: My inclination here would be to use measure theory concepts.  For example, the distance between two sets would be the measure of their symmetric difference.

Comment: @Paul thanks for your input. I think $d(A,B)$ is defined when $A\subset B$, since $f$ is defined over a sigma algebra, in which case the distance would reduce to: $\left|\sup_{x \in A, \;y \in B\cap A^c } |f(x)-f(y)| - \sup_{x \in B } |f(x)-f(\emptyset)|\right|$

Comment: @Paul It does seem that no matter what road I take, I am led to the need to turn $\mathcal{A}$ into a metric space or a measure space. Do you know of any more generic/abstract approaches that does not require this (I am starting to doubt this)

Comment: Have you looked at finite spaces?  I think you can come up with appropriate definitions in a finite space without recourse to metrics or measurability, and that might give you guidance to a more general case.

Comment: @Paul (+1)thanks, great idea, I'll take a look. If you are giving me a hint and know then answer, then feel free to post it as well.

Comment: No hint, just curious how it turns out :)

Comment: @Paul looks like there's no escaping measure....of course, that makes sense in hindsight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I did a bit of digging and it appears that the derivative of a set function is not defined for an *arbitrary* family of sets $\mathcal{A}$. The sets in $\mathcal{A}$ need to be measurable to admit a limiting process.

This means that the general expression is, in fact, the Radon-Nikodym theorem. I consulted my Advanced Calc book (*Advanced Calculus* by Buck, 3ed), and found a similar discussion restricted to the class of *Jordan-measurable* sets (they are defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and have an "area").

If we let $m(A)$ be the Jordan measure of a set $A\in \mathcal{A}$, then we can define the derivative of a set function $f(A)$ defined for $A \in \mathcal{A}$ along the "line" of sets $A_I:=A_1 \supset A_2 \supset ... \supset A$ simply as:

$$\frac{df}{dm}(A_I):= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(A_{i+1})-f(A_{i})}{m(A_i\setminus A_{i+1})} $$

Similar approaches could be used for more exotic spaces, so long as they are measurable. Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space, with measure $\mu \geq 0$ and $f(A)$ be a set function defined for $A\in \mathcal{F}$, then for a decreasing sequence of sets $A_I:=A_1 \supset A_2  ... \supset A: \lim_{n\to \infty} A_n = A$, we have:

$$\frac{df}{d\mu}(A_I):= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(A_{i+1})-f(A_{i})}{\mu(A_i\setminus A_{i+1})} $$

Maybe we can also get something like "unique derivative" $\frac{df}{d\mu}(S)$ of a set function evaluated at some set $S \in \mathcal{F}$ *iff*:

$$\lim B_i = \lim A_i = S \in \mathcal{F}\implies \frac{df}{d\mu}(B_I) = \frac{df}{d\mu}(A_I)\;\forall B_I,A_I \in \mathcal{F}$$

Anyway, that's as far as I've gotten. I'll happily accept another's answer if it can expand and/or correct this post.