# What does local differentiability with respect to metrics mean?

Tags: derivatives, metric-spaces

Let $\langle\mathbb{X},d\rangle$ and $\langle\mathbb{Y},\varrho\rangle$ be metric spaces, and $\psi\colon\mathbb{X}\to\mathbb{Y}$ be a (measurable) map. What does it precisely mean for $\psi$ to be *locally differentiable* with respect to $d$ and $\varrho$? I can guess at the meaning, but I would like a precise definition.

[If required, take $\mathbb{X}$ and $\mathbb{Y}$ to be compact spaces.]

Here's my guess:

$$\forall G~\text{open in}~\mathbb{X},~\lim\limits_{G\ni x\to\xi}\frac{\varrho(\psi(x),\psi(\xi))}{d(x,\xi)}$$

exists in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why not tell us what you guess it to be, instead of letting people imagine? That way, people won't waste their time telling you it is what you think it is.

Comment: @FlybyNight Added my guess, though it doesn't fully make sense to me. I want a precise definition.

Comment: Only a guess: If $f:R^k \rightarrow (X,d)$ is a map from Euclidean space to metric space X, then we may consider $\lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{d(f(x+t\xi), f(x)}{|t|}$. If I remember accurately, for lipschitz $f$ this limit exists for all $\xi$ at almost all $x$. It gives  a semi-norm on $R^k$. This seminorm is the metric derivative of $f$ at $x$. Now, could what we want be a map such that acts in a certain way on the two semi-norms of $f$ and $\Psi o f : R^k \rightarrow Y$ ?!

Comment: @Desire The authors of the paper do not define the term, but by the way they've used it, I suspected it might be some standard notion I am not aware of. Seems I was wrong!

Comment: @Desire Here's the paper: A measure-theoretic computational  method for inverse sensitivity problems III:  Multiple quantities of interest, T. Butler, D. Estep, S. Tavener, C. Dawson, J. Westerink, SIAM ASA Journal on Uncertainty Quantification, 2 (2014), 174-202. They mention 'local differentiability' toward the end of page 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guess you stated, 
$$\exists \lim\limits_{G\ni x\to\xi}\frac{\varrho(\psi(x),\psi(\xi))}{d(x,\xi)} \tag1$$
is not a good way to define differentiability on metric spaces, because, for example, the only maps $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ that are differentiable under the above definition are constant maps. (Sketch: think about the level curve of $\psi$ passing through $\xi$; since $\varrho(\psi(x),\psi(\xi))=0$ for $x$ on this curve, the  limit (1) would have to be zero everywhere, and so the map must be constant.)

There are workable definitions of differentiability in metric spaces: see [Differentiability in metric spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614688/differentiability-in-metric-spaces). However, in the [paper under consideration](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/130930406) the maps are from a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ (see the first paragraph of section 2 on page 3). So, the authors use the regular concept of differentiability for such maps, even though they will also put some non-Euclidean metric on those subsets.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Just to clarify, by local differentiability, they mean that the regular (Euclidean) derivative exists in every open neighborhood? I saw that $\mathbf{\Lambda}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ in the paper were subsets of Euclidean spaces, but since it specifically mentions "with respect to the metrics", I thought it might be something special.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure the authors themselves know what they mean, given the nature of the paper. "Locally differentiable" makes little sense; differentiability is already a local property. Just ignore their exercises in theory and read the calculations they do to see if there is any meaning in the paper at all.