# Why aren't derivatives defined on metric spaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, metric-geometry

I'm studying the book by Ambrosio on gradient flows in metric spaces. It's stated that the usual notion of gradient flow, $$ x'(t) = -\nabla_x f(x),$$ is not defined on metric spaces because we don't have a definition for $x'(t)$ nor $\nabla_x$. This is stated as obvious but it's not 100% clear to me.

I guess that since derivatives on a metric space *would* be defined as $$ f'(x) = \lim_{h\downarrow 0} \frac{d(f(x), f(x+h))}{h}$$ (where $d$ is a metric), we need to ensure that **limits** exist in the metric space. I thought of the discrete metric space where $d(x,y) = 0$ if $x=y$ and $1$ if $x\neq y$. But in this case, we can't define differentiable functions other than ones that are constant on singleton points. Is there a better example?

Another thing that might be needed to define derivatives is the idea of **direction**. Since
the gradient is essentially a set of directional derivatives in the basis vectors of the  underlying space (correct me if this is wrong?), we may not be able to define this in a metric space that doesn't have "directions".

What are some pathological examples of metric spaces that don't have directions or for other reasons we can't define derivatives? Is there anything else preventing derivatives/gradients from being defined in metric spaces?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_derivative

Comment: @user yeah, I get that we have to limit ourselves to working with only norms in the metric case. But I want to know what exactly it is that's preventing us from defining derivatives.

Comment: What do you mean by "norms" in metric space? And I think you don't want to define derivatives on a space but derivatives *of a function* that has value in the metric space? The link gives such examples. what kind of functions do you have in mind?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614688/differentiability-in-metric-spaces

Comment: Also, metric spaces tend to be "crinkly" --  https://twitter.com/johncarlosbaez/status/1304454125170561025 -- so there is no coherent analog to "the set of tangent lines/planes/etc." from which a derivative can come (i.e., there need not be a [tangent space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space) at each point of a metric space).

Comment: @user yeah, derivatives of a function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I'm looking for some more concrete examples where derivatives fail to exist

Comment: It needs to be the other way around $f:\mathbb{R}\to X$. Otherwise, one cannot make sense of the addition $x+h$ in $X$: general metric spaces have no vector space structures.

Comment: @user ah yes, thanks!

Comment: Note that we are talking about two different kinds of derivatives, $\nabla_x f$ is a derivative of a function defined on the metric space, while $x_t$ is the derivative of a function with values in a metric space. For the latter one, if you look at the limit you wrote as a definition of derivative, that always gives a non negative number (when the limit is defined) and doesn’t quite tell you in which direction the curve $x$ is going.

Comment: @EricTowers thanks for the references! The first SE question is exactly what I'm asking but the answers seem to only give the solution to the problem (spaces where derivatives are defined) rather than explaining what the problem is. whereas your point about crinkly spaces is what I'm looking for! Is this 'crinkliness' somehow like nondifferentiability of a surface? I don't understand how we can define this surface at all though, since we don't have 'directions' on a metric space

Comment: What you try to do is [embed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding) the metric space in a higher dimensional Euclidean space so that the metric distance between points matches the Euclidean distance between their images in the larger space (see also [isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry)).  For that embedding to yield an image smooth enough to have tangents everywhere is very special.

Comment: Given a path $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to X$ and a function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$, it makes perfect sense to differentiate $f\circ\gamma$. To define gradients/velocities, though, we need to find subsets of well-behaved paths and well-behaved functions to ensure that *any* such composition $f\circ \gamma$ is differentiable. This is easy to do on differentiable manifolds, but not so easy on general metric spaces.

Comment: There's a question whether such an object should morally be called a derivative. To me, "derivative" means "linear approximation." That's the point of a derivative, to talk about the first order behavior of some object. Your definition is obviously meaningful and formally similar to the derivative of real functions; I just don't know whether that's enough to be called a derivative.

Comment: Also relevant is the notion of *upper gradient*, denoted $|\nabla f|$ and defined by $|\nabla f|(x) = \limsup_{y \to x} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{d(x,y)}$.  It always exists at every limit point $x$ (possibly infinite), but of course there is no linear structure.

Comment: @NateEldredge by no linear structure do you mean the upper gradient is not linear in $x$? Is the motivation for the upper gradient the fact that we don't have directions in a metric space (and what's an example of a MS that doesn't have direction?)

Comment: I mean that it's not linear in $f$.  "Linear in $x$" doesn't even make sense as you cannot add or scale points of an abstract metric space. I don't think asking for a counterexample makes sense unless you can come up with a precise definition of "direction".  Part of the problem is that there *isn't* any satisfactory definition in the context of metric spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you consider functions $f : \mathbb R \to X$ into a metric space $(X,d)$. But your definition
$$ f'(t_0) = \lim_{h\downarrow 0} \frac{d(f(t_0), f(t_0+h))}{h}$$
does not make much sense.

1. If this limits exists, it must be $0$.
   $\phantom{x}$
   To see this, simply observe that for $h > 0$ we have $\frac{d(f(t_0), f(t_0+h))}{h} \ge 0$ and for $h < 0$ we have $\frac{d(f(t_0), f(t_0+h))}{h} \le 0$. Thus we get $\lim_{h\downarrow 0} \frac{d(f(t_0), f(t_0+h))}{h} \ge 0$ and  $\lim_{h\downarrow 0} \frac{d(f(t_0), f(t_0+h))}{h} \le 0$.
2. To avoid this problem, we could replace $h$ in the denominator by $\lvert h \rvert$. But then we get a concept of a derivative which can only take values $\ge 0$.
3. In my opinion a minimal requirement for a general definition of the derivative $f'(t_0)$ of a function $f : \mathbb R \to X$ with values in metric space $X$ is that for $X = \mathbb R$ it agrees with the usual derivative $f'(t_0)$. This is not the case with the above definitions.
4. A general *conceptual* problem that your derivative $f'(t_0)$ always is a real number. This is inadequate for $X \ne \mathbb R$, even in simple cases like $X = \mathbb R^2$.

The "classic" idea to introduce the derivative $f'(t_0)$ of a function $f : \mathbb R \to V$ into a normed linear space $(V, \lVert - \rVert)$ is to find the *best linear approximation* at a point $t_0$. Since the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb R$, such a linear (or better *affine*) function has the form
$$\ell_v(t) = f(t_0) + (t-t_0)v$$
with some $v \in V$. The **best** linear approximation is characterized by the property
$$\lim_{h\downarrow 0} \frac{\lVert f(t_0+h) -  \ell_v(t_0+h) \rVert}{\lvert h \rvert} = \lim_{h\downarrow 0} \frac{\lVert f(t_0+h) -  f(t_0) - hv \rVert}{\lvert h \rvert} = 0.$$
If this is satisfied for some $v \in V$, we say that $f'(t_0) = v$ is the derivative of $f$ at $t_0$. But we can also say that $\ell_v$ is the best approximation of $f$ at $t_0$ by a linear function. Linear functions are
understood as the simplest functions which can be very easily computed.

This approach heavily uses the linear structure of $V$. Nevertheless it can be generalized to arbitrary metric spaces. What we need is set $\mathcal F$ of functions $s :\mathbb R \to X$ which we understand as "simple". Then we can say that $f :\mathbb R \to X$ has a best approximation at $t_0$ by a function in $\mathcal F$ if there exists $s \in \mathcal F$ such that

$$\lim_{h\downarrow 0} \frac{df(t_0+h) , s(t_0+h) )}{\lvert h \rvert} = 0.$$

Comment: I think you misunderstood the notation $h\downarrow 0$, which in the context of the question, means $h\to 0+$, which implies that $h>0$.